# Trigger.io IOS package duplicating files

Tags: ios, trigger.io, ipa

I have for the first time went to build my production IOS app with trigger.io and was a little shocked at the file size so when I went to look at the IPA I noticed that in the root of the IPA it had the splash screen images and in the src directory it had the same images.

This accounted for about 10 extra megs, when you start having all the different resolutions for IPAD Iphone etc these files cane be large.

So it looks like the IPA creation process grabs the files from the src directory and places them in the root of the IPA but does not remove them from the src location and now I have double the images I need and double the size at that.

Comment: Yep, this is not ideal: it's a drawback we're aware of and have plans to fix in a future platform version - we're talking with customers now to find the most convenient alternative.

Comment: Hi James, I don't understand the need for the duplication though? Cant you just have the system not duplicate the files or just simply remove them once they have copied them over to the src directory?

I cant justify putting out a 20 meg app simply to have some pretty launch images. I would assume other customers would feel the same way

Comment: On iOS, the launchimages have to have specific names, and exist in a specific place (hence the copying). Removing the files from src after the copy would reduce the IPA size, but customers might want to use the launchimage from inside their app, so we can't do that all the time. We are working on a fix! In the meantime, 10MB for the images does seem high, compared to other customers... would a plainer / better compressed alternative work as a stop-gap?

Comment: Hi James, I am in the process of compressing them more right now. Just something I will have to do until a fix is in place, as for them being on the high end they are but with the better displays low quality images cheapen the app. One thing that might work is just to have a checkbox in the admin section that would maybe say, remove launchImage and it would then not add it as part of the IPA. Also I think the IPA should also remove the Android Launch images as well as they serve not purpose, although I guess I can remove them when I build but I think the system should. Just being picky I guess